# Bidirectional Vagrant Rsync

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, rsync

I have configured Vagrant to use Rsync shared folders instead of the (incredibly SLOW) `vboxsf` filesystem provided by VirtualBox by default:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "rsync",
        rsync__args: ["--verbose", "--archive", "-z"]
end
```

Obviously, there's more configuration, but I found these instructions [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/website/docs/source/v2/synced-folders/rsync.html.md) and they generally work in synchronizing from the host to the guest.

However, I need the guest to be able to sync back to the host, as some of my build tools are only installed on the guest. How can I sync bidirectionally in the shared folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately no, 
quote from [documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/rsync.html):

> The rsync synced folder does a one-time one-way sync from the machine running to the machine being started by Vagrant.

so better for you to use [NFS](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/nfs.html) (or [SMB](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/smb.html) if using a Windows host)

> In some cases the default shared folder implementations (such as VirtualBox shared folders) have high performance penalties. If you're seeing less than ideal performance with synced folders,

Comment: This is false; the vagrant box is visible as a computer on the network.  You can `scp` to it or from it as you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31764721/5419599  So you could just do a recursive `scp`.  I'm sure there is a way to `rsync` as well, even if not automatically.

Answer (score 18):

Consider using a vagrant plugin https://github.com/smerrill/vagrant-rsync-back#vagrant-rsync-back

Install:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-rsync-back
```

Run:

```
vagrant rsync-back
```

It'll rsync the mapped folders from guest to host

Answer (score 3):

Consider using this vagrant plugin
http://github.com/dmatora/vagrant-unison
It does realtime bidirectional folder sync